# Triggers not working when inserting data through OPEN XML in sql ser

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have created a trigger for a **asset_verification**. Whenever a new record is inserted in this table, the same record is inserted in the **asset_verification_history** table because of this trigger.

The trigger is as follows

```
Create trigger [dbo].[tr_insert_after_asset_verification] on [dbo].[asset_verification]
for insert
As
Begin
        declare @verification_id int
        declare @id int
        declare @audit_id int
        declare @date date
        declare @status varchar(15)
        declare @remarks varchar(200)
        declare @creationDate datetime
        declare @modificationDate datetime
        declare @updatedBy int
        declare @audit_action varchar(20)

        Select @verification_id = i.verification_id from inserted i

        If @verification_id IS NOT NULL
        Begin
        Select @id = i.id from inserted i
        Select @audit_id = i.audit_id from inserted i
        Select @date = i.date from inserted i
        Select @status = i.status from inserted i
        Select @remarks = i.remarks from inserted i
        Select @creationDate = i.creationDate from inserted i
        Select @modificationDate = i.modificationDate from inserted i
        Select @updatedBy = i.updatedBy from inserted i

        set @audit_action = 'Insert Record'

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[asset_verification_history]
           ([verification_id]
           ,[id]
           ,[audit_id]
           ,[date]
           ,[status]
           ,[remarks]
           ,[creationDate]
           ,[modificationDate]
           ,[updatedBy]
           ,[audit_action])
     VALUES
           (@verification_id
           ,@id
           ,@audit_id
           ,@date
           ,@status
           ,@remarks
           ,@creationDate
           ,@modificationDate
           ,@updatedBy
           ,@audit_action)

           End
End
```

When I insert the data in the asset_verification table using a procedure in which OPEN XML is used, then this trigger works only for the first record. For the rest of the records the trigger doesn't work

The procedure is as follows

```
Create procedure [dbo].[usp_AddVerificationBulkData]
(
@vXML XML
)
As
Begin
DECLARE @DocHandle INT

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @vXML

     Update asset_verification
     set 
     audit_id = x.AuditId,
     id = x.SerialId,
     date = x.VerificationDate,
     status = x.Status
     ,remarks = x.Remarks
     ,creationDate = x.CreatedOn
     ,modificationDate = x.ModifiedOn
     ,updatedBy = x.ModifiedBy
     From 
     asset_verification a 
     Inner Join 
     OpenXml(@DocHandle,'/ArrayOfAssetVerificationModel/AssetVerificationModel',2)
     With(SerialId int, AuditId int, VerificationDate datetime, Status int, Remarks varchar(200), CreatedOn datetime, ModifiedOn datetime, ModifiedBy int) x
     On a.audit_id = x.AuditId where a.id = x.SerialId;


     INSERT INTO [dbo].[asset_verification]
           ([id]
           ,[audit_id]
           ,[date]
           ,[status]
           ,[remarks]
           ,[creationDate]
           ,[modificationDate]
           ,[updatedBy])
           select SerialId,AuditId,VerificationDate,Status,Remarks,CreatedOn,ModifiedOn,ModifiedBy from OpenXml(@DocHandle,'/ArrayOfAssetVerificationModel/AssetVerificationModel',2)
     With(SerialId int, AuditId int, VerificationDate datetime, Status int, Remarks varchar(200), CreatedOn datetime, ModifiedOn datetime, ModifiedBy int) x
     where SerialId NOT IN (select a.id from asset_verification a where a.audit_id = x.AuditId);
End
```

**Problem:-** How to make this trigger work for every record that is inserted through Open XML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made the classic mistake of thinking that triggers fire once-per-row. They dont, it's once-per-action, so the inserted pseudo table holds **all** the rows affected by the action. Your trigger needs to work in a set based manner, not row based. Try this;

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_insert_after_asset_verification] ON [dbo].[asset_verification] FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT  INTO [dbo].[asset_verification_history]
            ( [verification_id]
            ,[id]
            ,[audit_id]
            ,[date]
            ,[status]
            ,[remarks]
            ,[creationDate]
            ,[modificationDate]
            ,[updatedBy]
            ,[audit_action]
            )
            SELECT  i.verification_id
                    ,i.id
                    ,i.audit_id
                    ,i.date
                    ,i.status
                    ,i.remarks
                    ,i.creationDate
                    ,i.modificationDate
                    ,i.updatedBy
                    ,'Insert Record'
            FROM    inserted i
            WHERE   i.verification_id IS NOT NULL

END
```

As an aside, and strictly speaking, your original trigger will log one row, not necessarily the first.